# save html-formatted text to database

Tags: php, html, phpmyadmin

I want to save html-formatted text to database, but when I do that it is don't save html-symbols like < / > ' and others
This is how I read article from database for editing:

```
<p class="Title">Англійський варіант:</p>
    <textarea name="EN" cols="90" rows="20" value="<?php echo htmlentities($articleArr['EN'], ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8"); ?>" ></textarea>
```

after this generates such html-code:

```
<p class="Title">Англійський варіант:</p>
    <textarea name="EN" cols="90" rows="20" value="&lt;p class=&#039;Title&#039;&gt; привыт &lt;/p&gt;" ></textarea>
```

So, I expect that this text will appear in my text field, in html-code of this page it is, but in text area is no.

In database I save it as:

```
<p class="Title"> Hello </p>
```

So how can I do the follow:

1. Read from database
   html-formattedtext.
2. Show it in textarea element.
3. Edit and save it back to database.

Help me please, how can I save such texts properly, Thanx!

Comment: Are you sure it doesn't save html-symbols like < / >?

Comment: yes, it don't save such symbols

Comment: it does. it simply does.

Comment: As for the other symbols, such as ' or \ , always do `$ParentName = mysql_real_escape_string($ParentName);` and so on for the every variable you put into query in quotes

Comment: Textarea has both opening and closing tags. and no value attribute.

Comment: If it don't have value atribute - how can I save edited article to database? How to assign variable and textarea field? Why it was working ealier when I used value attribute??

Comment: Heh, he's right, didn't spot that.  Textareas work unlike most form inputs.  Looks like this `<textarea name="textarea">Stuff Goes In Between the Tags</textarea>` rather than `<textarea name="textarea" value="Stuff doesn't go in value"></textarea>`

Comment: Oh, also, the stuff between the tags is it's value, it all gets put into $_POST or $_GET or whatever by the name of the textarea element.  So, `<textarea name="comments">Blah blah blah blah blah</textarea>` would be $_POST['comments'] and would equal "Blah blah blah blah blah".  If you had a string $string = "Blah blah blah blah blah" and output `echo '<textarea name="comments">'.$string.'</textarea>';` then you'd get a text area with "Blah blah blah blah blah" prefilled in.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Try using `htmlspecialchars()` on the string to put into the DB, and then, when pulling it back out, use `htmlspecialchars_decode()`.  Might make a difference.

Comment: Certain characters have special significance in HTML, and should be represented by HTML entities if they are to preserve their meanings. This function returns a string with some of these conversions made; the translations made are those most useful for everyday web programming. If you require all HTML character entities to be translated, use htmlentities() instead.

Answer (score 3):

Save it to a nvarchar(max) field.

Make sure you use parameterized queries for security. Read

http://www.aspnet101.com/2007/03/parameterized-queries-in-asp-net/

http://msdn.microsoft.com/msdnmag/issues/04/09/SQLInjection/

with little changes to   Sql , you can apply to Mysql aslo

Answer (score 0):

there is no problem with save your html code in database. and no need for filter data before save .
but when you want to show it again in `textarea` you shoud `Escape` it.

in php you can use this code to escape html codes:

**PHP Function**

> see doc: [htmlspecialchars](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php)
>
> ```
> $cotnent = htmlspecialchars( $cotnent );
> ```

**Wordpress Functions:**

> see doc: [format_to_edit](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/format_to_edit/)
>
> ```
> $cotnent = format_to_edit( $cotnent , false );
> ```

OR

> see doc: [esc_textarea](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/esc_textarea/)
>
> ```
> $cotnent = esc_textarea( $cotnent );
> ```