# How to save html string into database

Tags: ios, objective-c, database, nsstring

I have this `html string`

```
<p><span style="color: #4f4f4f; font-family: Arial; font-size: 12px; font-style: normal; 
font-variant: normal; font-weight: normal; letter-spacing: normal; line-height: 
15.600000381469727px; orphans: 2; text-align: -webkit-left; text-indent: 0px; text-transform:
 none; white-space: normal; widows: 2; word-spacing: 0px; -webkit-text-size-adjust: auto; -
webkit-text-stroke-width: 0px; background-color: #ffffff; display: inline !important; float: 
none;">Numerical estimation is key in many craft and technical jobs where the ability to 
quickly and accurately estimate material quantities is essential. The speed at which you can 
answer these questions is the critical measure, as most people could achieve a very high sco
re given unlimited time in which to answer. You can therefore expect 25-35 questions in 10 
minutes or so.</span></p>
```

I want to store this in my `database`, but app is getting crashed while executing query.
Any idea if I should remove any particular `symbol` or anything or is it because of it's length?

Comment: Have you tried to save plain text? Any error messages?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4577904/save-html-formatted-text-to-database

Comment: Is there meant to be a `"` after `style`? Surely that would break  it..

Answer (score 4):

You should perform **SQL Escape** operations in general.

Answer (score 2):

As long as you're inserting it as a string it should work.. Try this:

```
    $htmlString = '<p><span style="color: #4f4f4f; font-family: Arial; font-size: 12px; font-style: normal; 
    font-variant: normal; font-weight: normal; letter-spacing: normal; line-height: 
    15.600000381469727px; orphans: 2; text-align: -webkit-left; text-indent: 0px; text-transform:
     none; white-space: normal; widows: 2; word-spacing: 0px; -webkit-text-size-adjust: auto; -
    webkit-text-stroke-width: 0px; background-color: #ffffff; display: inline !important; float: 
    none;">Numerical estimation is key in many craft and technical jobs where the ability to 
    quickly and accurately estimate material quantities is essential. The speed at which you can 
    answer these questions is the critical measure, as most people could achieve a very high sco
    re given unlimited time in which to answer. You can therefore expect 25-35 questions in 10 
    minutes or so.</span></p>';
```

I basically replaced the `""` with `''` because your string already contained double quotes and that would break.

As Ismet Alkan stated it is always good practice to perform [`SQL Escapes`](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=SQL+Escapes&aq=f&oq=SQL+Escapes&aqs=chrome.0.57&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#hl=en&sclient=psy-ab&q=SQL+Escapes&oq=SQL+Escapes&gs_l=serp.3..35i39j0i22i10i30l2j0i22i30.63302.63302.0.63537.1.1.0.0.0.0.55.55.1.1.0...0.0...1c.1.8.psy-ab.QPoZFSunGxo&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_cp.r_qf.&fp=3e547c9918f195e6&biw=1920&bih=979) when inserting data.

Also make sure your `database` column is compatible with the string, so setting the type as `TEXT` should do the trick.