# action button on datatable codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, datatable

Hi I successfully implemented data table on codeigniter but I got one problem I need on my last column table to have an action buttons like edit,delete

here's how I made my data table on codeigniter

On View

```
<div class="table-responsive">
        <table id="table" class="table">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Loan</th>
                    <th>Loan Type</th>
                    <th>Loan Amount</th>
                    <th>First Name</th>
                    <th>Last Name</th>
                    <th>Action</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            </tbody>
            <tfoot>
                <tr>
                    <th>Loan</th>
                    <th>Loan Type</th>
                    <th>Loan Amount</th>
                    <th>First Name</th>
                    <th>Last Name</th>
                    <th>Action</th>
                </tr>
            </tfoot>
        </table>

<script type="text/javascript">

    var table;

    $(document).ready(function() {

        //datatables
        table = $('#table').DataTable({ 

            "processing": true, //Feature control the processing indicator.
            "serverSide": true, //Feature control DataTables' server-side processing mode.
            "order": [], //Initial no order.

            // Load data for the table's content from an Ajax source
            "ajax": {
                "url": "<?php echo site_url('home/ajax_list')?>",
                "type": "POST"
            },

            //Set column definition initialisation properties.
            "columnDefs": [
            { 
                "targets": [ 0 ], //first column / numbering column
                "orderable": false, //set not orderable
            },
            ],

        });

    });
    </script>
```

Now here's my script from my controller where in I pass my data through json.

```
public function ajax_list()
    {
        $list = $this->employee->get_datatables();
        $data = array();
        $no = $_POST['start'];
        foreach ($list as $customers) {
            $no++;
            $row = array();
            $row[] = $no;
            $row[] = $customers->loan;
            $row[] = $customers->loan_type;
            $row[] = $customers->loan_amount;
            $row[] = $customers->firstname;
            $row[] = $customers->lastname;

            $data[] = $row;
        }

        $output = array(
                        "draw" => $_POST['draw'],
                        "recordsTotal" => $this->employee->count_all(),
                        "recordsFiltered" => $this->employee->count_filtered(),
                        "data" => $data,
                );
        //output to json format
        echo json_encode($output);
    }
```

Is it possible to add an action buttons on datatables?

Comment: Try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4577962/11988937), this will help you

Comment: how can save-html-formatted-text-to-database help me sir

Comment: You can use textarea and type html in that and before save use `htmlspecialchars()`, this will help to save html in database and while pull back from database use `htmlentities()`

Answer (score 3):

If someone might encounter like this problem maybe this would help you.

```
$row = array();
            $row[] = $no;
            $row[] = $customers->loan;
            $row[] = $customers->loan_type;
            $row[] = $customers->loan_amount;
            $row[] = $customers->firstname;
            $row[] = $customers->lastname;
            $row[] = '<button type="button" name="update" id="'.$customers->id.'" class="btn btn-warning btn-xs update">Update</button>';
```

I added the button directly from the data array